# Can't see the list template to be available for creating new list on create screen in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list

I am working on SharePoint Foundation 2010 environment.

I have a custom list (Generic Template is used for creating this list). I have prepared a template out of it. Now, the Template ID of this template is 100 as we created it from a Generic List.

When i change the value in 'TemplateType' tag in the manifest file from 100 to some custom value (Say 1001) and upload it again in the List Template Gallery, everything seems to be fine. But, the problem is when i open the 'Create' screen, i can't find this template to be available for creating new list out of it.

Can somebody figure out what the problem is ?

Answer (score 1):

The rules of SharePoint states that the ListTemplate Type for custom list definitions should be at least 1000, but failing that isn't usually making it not show up in the create screen.

Make sure Hidden isn't specified as TRUE.

If this doen't help then add the elements.xml to the question so we can see it.

Comment: Thanks for the response PER. When you said 'Make sure Hidden isn't specified as TRUE.', I am not sure where shall i look for 'Hidden' attribute for TRUE value. Can you please elaborate. Another thing is when i extract the List Template i only get a manifest.xml file. I don't get elements.xml.